# SBS 2011 WSUS Updates Failing on Windows 8 client with error 800B0001

Tags: wsus, windows-sbs-2011, windows-8

We recently set up an SBS 2011 Standard SP1 domain and manage all optional updates from this server. Critical/Security updates are configured to automatically install without approval. WSUS is currently version 3.2.7600.226.

We have three computers running Windows 8 Pro 6.2.9200. These computers fail to check for updates giving the error code 800B0001. I have researched this error code, and followed all the suggested fixes, including a complete manual deletion of all update related files and registry entries on the client, and letting Windows re-build them. I also un-joined and re-joined to the domain. Nothing helps, I still get the same error. The server reports "Unknown" for the update status of these machines.

I have removed these three computers from the update management from the server, yet the client machines still fail to check for updates. The only work-around I have is to dis-join from the domain, install updates, then re-join the domain. I cannot continue doing it this way. It appears that SBS 2011 simply does not like Windows 8.

I found [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sus/archive/2012/09/05/additional-note-on-kb-2734608-regarding-wsu-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) regarding this exact issue. I found and downloaded this update, but when I went to install it on the server, it claimed the update is not applicable to that OS (even though I picked the perfect match).

NOTE: WSUS appears to think these Windows 8 clients are `Windows XP Pro x64 Edition`.

IMPORTANT NOTE: It was brought to my attention that these three machines used to run Windows 7 Pro, and an upgrade to Windows 8 Pro was installed on top of it. I have a hunch that this somehow broke the relationship with the server.